# Как предоставить доступ боту к айди фотографиям на телеграм серверах?

Tags: telegram, бот

Есть идея телеграм бота. В этой идеи один телеграм бот принимает фотографии при регистрации, а второй телеграм бот отправляет эти фотографии любым пользователям которые попросят бота им отправить фото. При приеме фотографии первый бот записывает айди фотографии, а сама фотография хранится на серверах телеграма. Второй же бот показывает фото по айди. Но проблема в ом что второй бот не имеет доступа к этим айди фотографий. Может можно передать права доступа этому боту?

Comment: а для чего заводить двух ботов для этого?

Comment: как сказал @ZxNuClear, для этого можно использовать одного бота, реализовав два основополагающих метода отправки фотографии и запроса фотографии по id, так гораздо проще будет реализовать кодом вашу задачу, сохраняя те же фотографии на хост, генерируя айдишники в базе с полем пути до фотографии. Я думаю что данная наводка позволит вам поразмыслить над архитектурой в целом.

Comment: так и сделаю! Спасибо за ответы!